# React Native Multi Component Form

Tags: javascript, react-native

Trying to think of a good solution to this issue, I am trying to create a Form which would exist on multiple pages. At one point if you press an option on one of the buttons on page 1, it will bring you to page 2 where you select something, and then go back to page 1. The issue I am having is writing the code so that it will rember what was currently on page 1, and can pass the information from page 2 to page 1.

I am assuming I am going to have to use some sort of state management system to pull this off, but honestly have no clue. RIght now all I use is react native flux for navigation for page to page.. and thought about just passing everything as props.. but that seems clunky

Any help would be awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if your form is simple and you do need to have multiple screens, I see no reason not to use the props injected by react-native-router-flux. But if you are looking for something that can scale a bit better, why not try to put your form data in a temporal object inside your state manager. For the sake of the example, let's say [redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux). Create a reducer that stores an object with all the form data, and bind your different screens so that they can access it. Then, through actions, update the values when the user inputs something. There might be a few tricky edge cases, such as clearing all data when the form is submitted, what happens if the user cancels the action, etc... Sure, it looks a bit cumbersome to handle data in such a way, but I think it could be a nice solution.

Comment: Thanks.. thats the push I needed haha